# Error in read.table, how to set column name as row.name?

Tags: r, read.table

Can anyone explain what's going on here? setting `row.name= NULL` makes no difference compared to when I dont specify it, yet when I set `row.names=1`, it says duplicate row.names not allowed? How do I resolve this to get column V1 as rownames?

```
ak1a = read.table("/Users/abhaykanodia/Desktop/smallRNA/AK1a_counts.txt", row.names = NULL)
head(ak1a)
                  V1 V2
1 ENSG00000000003.15  2
2  ENSG00000000005.6  0
3 ENSG00000000419.14 21
4 ENSG00000000457.14  0
5 ENSG00000000460.17  2
6 ENSG00000000938.13  0
ak1a = read.table("/Users/abhaykanodia/Desktop/smallRNA/AK1a_counts.txt")
head(ak1a)
                  V1 V2
1 ENSG00000000003.15  2
2  ENSG00000000005.6  0
3 ENSG00000000419.14 21
4 ENSG00000000457.14  0
5 ENSG00000000460.17  2
6 ENSG00000000938.13  0
ak1a = read.table("/Users/abhaykanodia/Desktop/smallRNA/AK1a_counts.txt", row.names = 1)
Error in read.table("/Users/abhaykanodia/Desktop/smallRNA/AK1a_counts.txt",  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

Comment: As the error says, "duplicate row names are not allowed". You likely have repeated values in `V1`.

Comment: Read about make.unique

Answer (score 1):

From the helpfile you can read:

> If there is a header and the first row contains one fewer field than the number of columns, the first column in the input is used for the row names. Otherwise if **row.names is missing, the rows are numbered**.

That explains the same behavior when you set row.names=NULL or when you use its default value.

You can set row.names as in this example:

```
df <- read.table(text="V1 V2
ENSG00000000003.15  2
ENSG00000000005.6  0
ENSG00000000419.14 21
ENSG00000000457.14  0
ENSG00000000460.17  2
ENSG00000000938.13  0", header=TRUE, row.names=letters[1:6])
```

which displays:

```
                  V1 V2
a ENSG00000000003.15  2
b  ENSG00000000005.6  0
c ENSG00000000419.14 21
d ENSG00000000457.14  0
e ENSG00000000460.17  2
f ENSG00000000938.13  0
```

Comment: Hello @Jilber. thanks for your answer. It is really helpful. However, I want column V1 to be my row names as it is specific gene id which will be converted to gene name later

Answer (score 0):

The first two executions are functionally the same, when you don't use row.names parameter of read.table, it's assumed that its value is NULL.

The third one fails because `1` is interpreted as being a vector with length equal to the number of rows filled with the value 1. Hence the error affirming you can't have two rows with the same name.

What you're doing with `row.names=1` is equivalent trying to do:

```
test <- read.table(text="X Y
1 2
3 4", header=TRUE)
row.names(test) = c(1,1)
```

It gives the same Error.

If you want to name your rows `R1:RX` why not try something like this:

```
ak1a = read.table("/Users/abhaykanodia/Desktop/smallRNA/AK1a_counts.txt")
row.names(ak1a) = paste("R",1:dim(ak1a)[1],sep="")
```

Comment: Hello @Deigo thanks for your answer. However, I want column V1 to be my row names as it is specific gene id which will be converted to gene name late

Comment: Sorry to have taken so long to reply, If you want your row names to all be V1, you can't because that would not be unique (you would run into the same error), however if you just want V1:VX, just change the last line of code to use "V" instead of "R"